# How to refresh hibernate entity when have relationship with other entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to refresh my entity using simply hibernate code:

```
session.refresh(myEntity);
```

Problem is that. This entity has relationship to other entity:

```
class MyEntity{

     private OtherEntity otherEntity:

}
```

When I first time load object I use query like:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from myEntity mEnt"
        + " join fetch mEnt.otherEntity");
```

All is loaded. But when I refresh object.

```
session.refresh(myEntity);
```

Relationship entity (otherEntity) is not loaded, is null. I am using LAZY initialization.

Anyone know how to fix it? I will be grateful for help.

Comment: is your entity `MyEntity` `cacheable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add Cascade-Refresh action to MyEntity.otherEntity property (@CascadeType.REFRESH).

[CascadeType.REFRESH explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403681/what-does-cascadetype-refresh-actually-do)

[cascadin conception](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/orm/cascading.html)

Try to add this by annotation or by XML (I dont know which type you use). Good luck.